# Is there a SQL command that I can run to get all the expired transients in WordPress?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am wanting to get a list of all expired transients in WordPress. I am aware of using

```
wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE ('%\_transient\_%')
```

But, I want to fetch only those that are expired. How can I do that? Any idea about that?

Comment: as we don't know your tables, we also don't know when a whatever is expired. so add table and explain  which of the products should be shown

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help of [delete_expired_transients](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_expired_transients/) to create your select query for expired transients.